# What Is Causing Error 5009 from MS-Graph API on Calendar.GetSchedule Call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to make a GetSchedule call to MS-Graph and all SMTPs I provide in the call get kicked out with error code 5009 and this message:

```
Unable to resolve e-mail address xxxxx@yyyyy.onmicrosoft.com to an Active Directory object.
```

I have no problems using other Exchange-related Graph calls for calendars, e.g. CalendarView and change notification subscriptions.

In my GetSchedule call, all the SMTPs I initially provided were for resource rooms, which do not have a user license assigned in O365, but I later included a "real user" SMTP, and got the same error.

The call looks like this:

```
   var ret = m_Client.Users[m_Email].Calendar.GetSchedule(smtpList, endTime, startTime, 30)
               .Request()
               .Header("Prefer", $"outlook.timezone=\"{timeZone.Id}\"")
               .PostAsync().Result;
```

I cannot find any explanation for this error.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad--I got the domain wrong.  My onmicrosoft domain has no dash in it, but my local test domain does, and sometimes the fingers just stick a dash in.  Doh.